# list all google+ pages owned by "me"

Tags: api, google-plus

is it possible to list all google+ pages owned by "me" after being successfully authenticated? I've searched on the official documentation, here: https://developers.google.com/+/api/ but doesn't seem possible.

I reckon the function must be implemented somewhere as it's displayed in google's switch account panel, but it's probably not exposed to the public?

[image]